# $L^1([0, 1]) \subset C([0, 1])^*$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

Basically my question is: how can I prove that $L^1([0, 1]) \subset C([0, 1])^*$, where $C([0, 1])$ represents all continuous functions on $[0, 1]$, and the superscript $^*$ means the dual space. Actually I want to ask this question for all compact manifolds with boundary, but I think answering the question in the $[0, 1]$ case will also give a general answer. Also, I am interested in knowing whether the above mentioned inclusion is also continuous. If this is standard material, then a reference would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show how an element $g \in L^1([0,1])$ corresponds to a bounded linear funtional $\varphi$ on $C([0,1])$.  The usual way to do this is:
$$
\varphi(f) = \int_0^1 f(t)\;g(t)\;dt,\qquad f \in C([0,1])
$$
So to complete this you have to show that the map $g \mapsto \varphi$ is what I claimed.

Comment: I see, so the inclusion is also continuous with norm $\leq 1$. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Even more, the inclusion is isometric: the $L_1$ norm of $g$ equals the operator norm of $\varphi$.